# How to install YAML extension on WAMP?

Tags: php, wamp, yaml

My environment is this:

```
Windows 7 64bit
Wamp 2.4
PHP 5.4.12
```

I have enabled the extension in the php.ini files at both locations viz. PHP and Apache:

```
extension=yaml.so
```

But `yaml_parse` is still shown as undefined.

Any advice on how to get YAML working on Wamp?

Comment: I believe to get php_yaml to work you also need to install the LibYAML.dll library as the php extension php_yaml is just a front end to that library which does most of the work. Unfortunately I cannot find anywhere reputable to download that dll from. So you may need to compile and link it yourself.

Comment: Yes! I read in a Google code thread that the process is a very long one and no dlls available!

Comment: Hi @RutwickGangurde I am also facing the same issue in windows env. Downloaded files from http://pecl.php.net/package/yaml. Can you please post your answer for this question.

Comment: Hi @Cakephp.Saint I never found a solution, unfortunately! Had to switch to an Ubuntu machine.

Comment: i cant get it working, it downloaded yaml from php.net, got php_yaml.ddl in ext dir, enable extension=php_yaml.dll but i dont know where to put the yaml.dll, i tried in the same folder or apache2 bin folder but without any success...

Comment: @Loenix It didn't for me either. I switched to an Ubuntu machine. You should do the same or use a VM.

Comment: @Rutwick Gangurde I finally succeeded by understanding how it works as this is very wrongly documented. Get the right version from here: http://pecl.php.net/package/yaml Download the DLL relying on you configuration (PHP5.6 VC11 => YAML 1.3, PHP7 VC14 => YAML 2.0). Extract TWO files, the php_yaml.dll file into C:\wamp64\bin\php\phpX\ext AND yaml.dll into C:\wamp64\bin\php\phpX\ . Take care of path ! Dont forget to add extension=php_yaml.dll to all you php.ini files

Comment: @Loenix Thank you very much! I am going to try this and respond.

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to solve this by following some hints from @Loenix.

You have to do as follows:

1. Download the corresponding php_yaml.dll from the official website. PHP under WAMP is threaded (https://pecl.php.net/package/yaml)
2. Extract the php_yaml.dll file and copy it to the following directory:

C:\wamp64\bin\php\php\ext

3. Add the following text (without quotes) "extension=php_yaml.dll" in  (and this is important) phpForApache.ini located in the C:\wamp64\bin\php\php\ directory
4. Right click on the WAMP tray icon and click Refresh

For me, step 3 was the trick since I was editing the php.ini file in the /bin/php/php directory, which seems to not be taken into consideration.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have written `extension=yaml.so` without any quotes.

Comment: Yes! It is without any quotes!